# How to sort date with 'MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss am/pm' in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, react-native

```
var array = [{ 
  id: 1, 
  date: 'Mar 12 2017   10:00:00 am'
},{
  id: 2,
  date: 'Mar 12 2017   08:00:00 pm'
},{   
  id: 3, 
  date: 'Mar 12 2017   05:00:00 am' 
},{ 
  id: 4, 
  date: 'Mar 18 2017   09:00:00 am'
}];
```

Here is my logic:-

```
sortedPatients = PatientsListArray.sort((a, b) => {
  if (b.Date < a.Date) return -1
  if (b.Date > a.Date) return 1
})
```

I'm getting output like this  `id4 , id1 , id2 , id3`

I expected output like this `id4, id2, id3, id1`

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

**Your code have some issues:**

You're comparing Strings rather than Date objects, So, you're sorting Strings :-)

```
if (b.Date < a.Date) return -1
    ^        ^
```

You're getting the Date string using a capitalized `Date` attribute.

```
if (b.Date < a.Date) return -1
      ^        ^
```

What you're expecting is incorrect because you want to get a Descending result `id4, id2, id1, id3`

```
id4, id2, id3, id1
          ^    ^
          ->
              <-
```

Your source array contains an invalid value for date attribute, so you need to wrap it with quotes `"`.

```
date: Mar 12 2017   10:00:00 am
     ^                         ^
```

You can use either `new Date()` constructor or the static function `Date.parse` (to get number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC).

> ## new Date()
>
> String value representing a date. The string should be in a format recognized by the Date.parse() method (IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps and also a version of ISO8601).
>
> **Note:** parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and Date.parse, they are equivalent) is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies. Support for RFC 2822 format strings is by convention only. Support for ISO 8601 formats differs in that date-only strings (e.g. "1970-01-01") are treated as UTC, not local. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

---

> ## Date.parse()
>
> The parse() method takes a date string (such as "Dec 25, 1995") and returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC. This function is useful for setting date values based on string values, for example in conjunction with the setTime() method and the Date object. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

**Look this code snippet with those fixes:**

```js
var array = [{
  id: 1,
  date: 'Mar 12 2017 10: 00: 00 am'
}, {
  id: 2,
  date: 'Mar 12 2017 08: 00: 00 pm'
}, {
  id: 3,
  date: 'Mar 12 2017 05: 00: 00 am'
}, {
  id: 4,
  date: 'Mar 18 2017 09: 00: 00 am'
}];

var sorted = array.sort((a, b) => { 
  //The parse function will convert those strings to Dates.
  var bdt = Date.parse(b.date); 
  var adt = Date.parse(a.date);
  return bdt > adt ? 1 : (bdt < adt ? -1 : 0);
});

console.log(sorted);
```

See? now your logic is working!

Comment: no, it's not working.  it's not sorting am/pm
my data is not static it comes from service
 PatientsListArray.sort((a, b) => {
            if (b.Date < a.Date) return -1
           if (b.Date > a.Date) return 1
        })

Answer (score 0):

Your sort logic is correct. The issue is because your `date` properties in the objects of your array are strings (despite the sample in your question missing the quotes delimiting the values - I presume you copy/pasted this from your console). Therefore they are compared alphanumerically. To fix this you need to convert them to `Date()` objects so the date comparison can be made.

Also note that JS is case-sensitive, so `a.Date` is not equal to `a.date`. Try this:

```js
var array = [{ 
  id: 1, 
  date: 'Mar 12 2017 10:00:00 am'
},{
  id: 2,
  date: 'Mar 12 2017 08:00:00 pm' 
},{   
  id: 3, 
  date: 'Mar 12 2017 05:00:00 am' 
},{ 
  id: 4, 
  date: 'Mar 18 2017 09:00:00 am' 
}];

var sortedPatients = array.sort((a, b) => {
  var aDate = new Date(a.date), bDate = new Date(b.date);
  if (bDate < aDate) return -1
  if (bDate > aDate) return 1
})

console.log(sortedPatients);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your date string is a parsable string (RFC2822 or (a variant of) ISO 8601 date) you can map your data to a tuple (array) of parsed date string and the index of that date. Then sort on the parsed date string (milliseconds after epoch) and then rebuild a new array using the indexes of the sorted array and original data.

```
var array = [{ 
  id: 1, 
  date: 'Mar 12 2017 10:00:00 am'
},{
  id: 2,
  date: 'Mar 12 2017 08:00:00 pm' 
},{   
  id: 3, 
  date: 'Mar 12 2017 05:00:00 am' 
},{ 
  id: 4, 
  date: 'Mar 18 2017 09:00:00 am' 
}];

var sorted = array.map(//map to tuple of epoch ms date and index
  ({date},index)=>[Date.parse(date),index]
)
.sort(//sort on epoch ms date
  (a,b)=>a[0]-b[0]
).reduce(//rebuild an array based on sorted indexes
  (all,[_,index])=>
    all.concat([array[index]]),
  []
);
```

Comment: Isn't this just overkill?

Comment: @Neo Is what not just overkill? If the array has lots of items then parsing string to date in sort handler is not the most effective way of doing it. If data is used somewhere else and you mutating it by sorting it causes an error that usually takes hours and hours to solve it (mutable shared state combined with asynchronous code for example) then not mutating anything may be a good idea

Answer (score 0):

You are using string comparison. You have to `Date.parse` to get timestamp in number

`array.sort((a, b) => Date.parse(b.date) - Date.parse(a.date))`